# Systemctl unable to start any service or even get status of any service

Tags: systemd, amazon-ec2

I rebooted my EC2 instance and even a simple command like `systemctl status xyz.service` gives me an error: `Failed to get properties: No such interface ''`

When I type in systemd I get:
`Trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd.`

What went wrong and how do I fix it?
I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: Whats the output of `file /sbin/init`?

Comment: /sbin/init: symbolic link to upstart

Comment: That means your `init` is now Upstart, not Systemd. Does the file `/lib/systemd/systemd` exist? Also try `sudo systemd --system` to change the init in-place.

Comment: /lib/systemd/systemd exists. sudo systemd --system hangs after these last messages:
`Failed to install release agent, ignoring: File exists
resolvconf.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=219/CGROUP
systemd-journal-flush.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd-journal-flush.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd-journal-flush.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lvm2-lvmetad.service: Supervising process 1537 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.`

Comment: Try a reboot then...

Comment: rebooted, got a different error message: `Failed to install release agent, ignoring: File exists
lvm2-lvmetad.service: Supervising process 1530 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
systemd-journal-flush.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd-journal-flush.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd-journal-flush.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

Comment: Try `sudo /bin/journalctl --flush`

Comment: `Failed to kill journal service: No such method 'KillUnit'`

Comment: That seems like a problem with the unit itself. Did you change anything recently?

Comment: not that I know of